# Advice on Instantiation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am quite the coding newbie, so please bear with me and my horrific code.

```
void ChickenInstantiate()
    {
        LocOfChkn.Add(spawnLoc);
        int i = 0;
        for (int ChickenCount = 0; ChickenCount < maxChickenCount; ChickenCount++)
        {
            while (Vector3.Distance(spawnLoc, LocOfChkn[i]) < 2)
            {
                spawnLoc = new Vector3(Random.Range(randXMin, randXMax), Random.Range(randYMin, randYMax), 1);
                spawnLoc.z = 5;
                i += 1;
                if (i >= LocOfChkn.Count)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Instantiate(ChickenPrefab1, spawnLoc, Quaternion.identity);
            LocOfChkn.Add(spawnLoc);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is some code for instating a prefab but making sure it doesn't instantiate within an area, and frankly I'm not sure how I should fix it- its completely broken; chickens don't appear, I'm not even sure if they spawn in the correct areas, etc. (the first instance of spawnLoc is defined at startup, btw)

I'm using the current latest version of unity and visual studio.

Comment: Where is `ChickenInstantiate` called?

Comment: Tips: 1) Make your namings _**descriptive**_. Avoid this "Loc" instead of "Location", "Chkn" instead of "Chicken", and other such acronym crap. Nevermind readability to thers; you are going to spend _**minutes**_ trying to decypher and understand your own code soon enough, just to save some _fractions of seconds_ of typing time; which you can save anyway on all but the first time by simply using your IDE's autocomplete hotkeys.

Comment: 2) Decide on a _**naming convention**_ and follow it. For any given type of data, ie fields, methods, classes, etc, you should not have camelCase in one place, PascalCase in another, and snake_case in another. Naming conventions will save you time and sanity. I suggest something like the one that is default in Rider / Resharper. It's what I use after trying many other naming conventions. Google it and you'll find it. --- Order also matters. If you use subject-action, like `chickenMovement` _here_, don't use `movementOfChiken` (action-subject) _there_. But that is much less standardized.

Comment: Assuming spawnLoc is a `Vector3`, it's not an 'instance', it's a struct. That means that modifying it after adding it to `LocOfChkn` won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should `Instantiate` a chicken for the first location you add to `locOfChkn`. This will serve as both making sure your code is running, and avoid a chickenless spot.
- Use VSCode or your favorite IDE to do a step-by-step evaluation of your function, to know exactly what is happening. Barring that, add `Debug.Log`s for each step.
- Check the hierarchy for any spawned chickens. Maybe they are disabled.

Now for other issues:

- Please follow a C# convention for writing code. Chkn and Loc are about as unintuitive as it gets.
- If you ignore the z position when evaluating distances, please consider using Vector2.Distance.
- Using a field for a value that you only use inside one function is useless. Simply set `spawnLoc` as a var inside `ChickenInstantiate`.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code

```
void InstantiateChicken()
{
    List<Vector3> chickenPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxChickenCount; i++)
    {
        bool doesCollide;
        Vector3 spawnLocation;
        do
        {
            spawnLocation = new Vector3(
                Random.Range(randXMin, randXMax),
                Random.Range(randYMin, randYMax),
                5);
            doesCollide = false;
            foreach (var pos in chickPositions)
            {
                if (Vector2.Distance(pos, spawnLocation) < 2f)
                    doesCollide = true;
            }
        }
        while (doesCollide);

        Instantiate(chickenPrefab1, spawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);
        chickenPositions.Add(spawnLocation);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, simply place all your chickens by hand, and make them offset their positions by a random factor when they spawn.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The inclusion of a Foreach loop had me recover some old memories; I had completely forgot about it's existence. The tips about convention were also quite helpful, and I've gone through my code and changed all of the errors.